# How set the application support multi screen in android?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I am creating an Android application. How do I set up multiple screen support?

How do I design a button background, background images, etc. for different screens using Photoshop?

Comment: This should help you http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

Comment: I hope the following links are help to you... http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Creating common layout structures in android?

Comment: @Mus how to set dpi in Photoshop to design widget

Comment: how to set dpi in Photoshop to design widget

Comment: can you explain your concept clearly ?

Comment: have tried 9 patch images?

Comment: ya i am create one image for 320x480(mdpi) in Photoshop,like one button in 40X60 it automatically fit for the screen.When i create the same button for 480 x 800(hdpi) button in 40X60 the pixels are not good to see.

Comment: ok..I am asking chaneg the ordinary image into 9 patch image? using android tools

Comment: both png and 9 patch image are same or different.

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj ya i got 9 patch android tool.but am not able to understand that usage of the tool clearly.

Comment: Because this will fix for all layout and then you create the drawable floder on res and store these images to that floder... try this way i hope so this will help to you...

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj if u have any tutorial link to describe those things clearly.

Comment: i hope this link will be help to you http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj thanks for the link.I have another doubt.am use runnable thread in my app,it slow my app how can i rectify it.